# How to increment object property (isbn in this example) by one, each time I add some item to the list:?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to increment object property (isbn in this example)  by one, each time I add some item to the list. 
I want to each tr have unique isbn(1,2,3,4...)
I tried with newItem.isbn++, but each time I add item I get 1 (not 2,3,4...).
I am new to JavaScript and I really need some help here.

```
 //Item Class
class Item {
    constructor(isbn, item, amount, price) {
        (this.isbn = isbn), (this.item = item), (this.amount = amount), (this.price = price);
    }
}
//UI Class
class UI {
    static displayItems() {
        const storedItems = [
            {
                isbn: '1',
                item: 'Some item',
                amount: '2',
                price: '$ 2500,00'
            }
        ];

        const items = storedItems;
        items.forEach((item) => UI.addItemToList(item));
    }

    static addItemToList(item) {
        const list = document.querySelector('tbody');
        const row = document.createElement('tr');

        row.innerHTML = `
        <td>${item.isbn}</td>
        <td>${item.item}</td>
        <td>${item.amount}</td>
        <td>${item.price}</td>
        <td>
            <a href=""><i class="material-icons prefix grey-text text-darken-3">delete</i></a>
        </td>
        `;
        list.appendChild(row);
    }

    static clearFields() {
        document.querySelector('#item').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#amount').value = '';
        document.querySelector('#price').value = '';
    }
}

//Event: Display Items
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayItems);
//Event: Add Items
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    //Prevent default of submit
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get values from form
    const isbn = 0;
    const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
    const amount = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
    const price = document.querySelector('#price').value;

    //Instatiate Item
    const newItem = new Item(isbn, item, amount, price);
    newItem.isbn++; //Here I need help!!!!!!!
    console.log(newItem);

    //Add item to UI
    UI.addItemToList(newItem);

    //Clear input fields
    UI.clearFields();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you would want your ISBN counter to be a global variable so that you may keep track of it through each iteration. Currently you are resetting it to zero every time you run that function since the variable is scoped to that function.

```
let isbn = 0;

// other code...

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
    const amount = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
    const price = document.querySelector('#price').value;

    newISBN = isbn++; // notice here we are incrementing the global variable

    const newItem = new Item(newISBN, item, amount, price); // here we are using this new incremented value to create your item

    UI.clearFields();
});
```

Comment: This would probably not happen here but `isbn` is exposed to everyone and can be freely changed (i.e. reset to `0` again).

Answer (score 1):

Some stateful helper could be a solution. I.e.,

```
const createNewISBN = (initial = 0) => {
    let isbn = initial;

    return function newIsbn() {
        isbn += 1;
        return isbn;
    }
}

const newIsbn = createNewIsbn(); // this will initiate new pool
```

Then later in your code:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    //Prevent default of submit
    e.preventDefault();
    //Get values from form
    const isbn = newIsbn(); // here no longer 0
    const item = document.querySelector('#item').value;
    const amount = document.querySelector('#amount').value;
    const price = document.querySelector('#price').value;

    //Instatiate Item
    const newItem = new Item(isbn, item, amount, price);
    // newItem.isbn++; //Here I need help!!!!!!! <-- this you don’t need anymore
    console.log(newItem);

    //Add item to UI
    UI.addItemToList(newItem);

    //Clear input fields
    UI.clearFields();
});
```